# Visual Studio 2012 platform toolset v110_xp

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to build a program using Visual Studio 2012. It's platform toolset property was set to 'v110_xp' but I changed it to 'v110'

Now I'm getting the error:

> Error 2   error MSB8020: The builds tools for v110_xp (Platform Toolset = 'v110_xp') cannot be found. To build using the v110_xp build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v110_xp to build using the v110_xp build tools.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets   44

- I already updated the VC++ Project and I also changed the platform toolset property to Visual Studio 2012 (v110) (it was originally set to v110_xp)
- I also opened the .vcxproj file in another editor and manually changed it to use v110.

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: can you explain your down vote, so I can adjust the question?

Answer (score 13):

I updated Visual Studio 2012 to Update 4 and that seems to fix it.